# How to calculate the set of leaders of basic blocks?

Tags: compiler-optimization

Here is the set of rules to calculate the set of leaders

1 The first tuple is a leader.
2 Tuple L is a leader if there is a tuple if ...goto L or goto L .
3 Tuple L is a leader if it immediately follows a tuple if ...goto B or goto B

I  understand 1 and 3 but  2 looks very confusing for me. Can someone clear up 2 with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology does not match what I am used to but I am assuming that a tuple is a generalized instruction/statement in the program.

Under that assumption the second rule states that if an instruction L is the target of a goto, i.e. if any instruction jumps to L, then L is the leader of a basic block. As an example, consider the following:

```
0: A = A + 1
1: B = A + 7
2: if A < 5 goto 6
3: A = A - 5
4: K = f(A)
5: Y = 12
6: Z = 12
7: return A
```

In this example, `0` is a leader according to rule 1 (it is the first instruction), `3` is a leader according to rule 3 (it immediately follows a jump), and `6` is a leader according to rule 2 (it is the target of a jump).